# When I try to browse to a site I get the localhost default page (WampServer)

Tags: theming, installation

I use WampServer, and just installed a theme drupal (Jollyany) on localhost, but when I click to explore the site, this sends me to localhost default page:

[image]

I try to see what happens when i get on the hosting. ... get me the following error:

[image]

Please help

Comment: Hi @GranGorila. Did you get this figured out? If so, please post your solution so that it can help others. :) In the meantime I have made a few edits to your question to make it a bit clearer. Cheers -

Answer (score 1):

Do you have properly configured /sites/defaults/settings.php? Looks like somthing in your connection is wrong, it can be database name, username or/and password.

Comment: And see to host for database. Most of hosting use default 'localhost', but some of them use 'mysql.sock' (like in your error) try to change them too if your db, user & pass is correct and error still showed.

Comment: the file "setting, php" in localhost is ok, except for the hosting, I edited and improved. Now the web is displayed. But the Clik problem persists in bothn (localhost and hosting),

in my localhost I returned to the panel, and hosting shows me the following message: http://i.imgur.com/sypoxDA.jpg

Comment: you should determine database name, db username, pass and very important the database host too. may be you have wrong host like localhost but the hosting provide mysql on another hostname. the second - delete whitespaces in those fields. and also check the files attributes. set up 755 for folders and 644 for all the files of your site

Comment: the host, the pass and name bd, this ok ...that rare :((